# LIghtbox image X Closed button align Top right on the image

Tags: lightbox2

I need to align the close button on the Top right of the image. I have tried to give the position but its not taking with the css.

```
.lb-closeContainer {
   position: absolute;
   top: -10px;
   right:40px;
 }
```

For the actual result, I have attached the image with it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.lb-data .lb-close {
display:block;
position:absolute;
right:50px;
top:5px;
/*float: right;*/
}
```

like that I resolved it

Comment: I am using lightbox-plus-jquery.js Please explain your answer with the jsfiddle to resolved the above issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API offered by the library to make this change so you will have to hack/monkeypatch it.

**Modifying the html.** The ideal way to do this would be to update the markup generated by lightbox.js and move the `<a>` tag with the `lb-close` class inside of `<div class="lb-container">` as pictured below. To do this, you could modify lightbox.js. On line 102 you can see the markup that is generated: https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/dev/dist/js/lightbox.js#L102

**Positioning with CSS.** Then you would need to apply some CSS for positioning the 'X' button:

```
position: absolute;
right: 16px;
top: 16px;
```

Oh and note that since the anchor tag with the `lb-close` has been moved, the CSS selector that previously styled it has been updated. Now it is simply `.lb-close`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this plugin js you need change the files lightbox.js and the lightbox.css (or respectives .min)

First:
In lightbox.js find:

```
<div class="lb-closeContainer"><a class="lb-close"></a></div>
```

and then cut and past inside

```
<div class="lb-outerContainer">
```

Now, in CSS you adjust the classes. Change all .lb-data .lb-close by .lb-outerContainer .lb-close and finally add style:

```
.lb-outerContainer .lb-close {
  position:absolute;
  right: -30px;
  top: -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.lb-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    right: 0;
}

div#lightbox {
    width: auto;
    left: 50% !important;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

[Seen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsbU7.jpg)

For another solution, You can explore this code on CodePen by following this link: https://codepen.io/AlexSND/pen/zXxWxV

Answer (score -1):

Solution from Lokesh Dhakar not quite right, tag with the lb-close class should be placed in the end of lb-nav class then the button will work correctly and display.
Also do not forget to add .lb-nav tag to .lb-close, so that it would be like this: .lb-nav a.lb-close {...}

Comment: I am using lightbox-plus-jquery.js Please explain your answer with the jsfiddle to resolve the above issue. Thanks in advance.